# How to show loader after updating data by queryClient.invalidateQueries?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, react-hooks, react-query

In my project, I am trying to redirect to the listed page after updating an item. The code is working properly but here I am facing an issue, the loader is not working.

```
export const useUpdateStatusArchiveSurvey = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: updateArchiveSurvey,

    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(['searched-public-survey']);
    },
  });
};
```

By using "invalidateQueries" the updated values are displayed in the list but the loader is not working.

```
...
...
const {
    data: queriedSurvey,
    fetchNextPage: fetchNextQueries,
    isLoading,
  } = useListAllPublicSurvey({
    query: search,
    status: tab,
    orderDesc: orderDesc,
    actionPlanId: actionValue?.id,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchNextQueries();
  }, [queriedSurvey, search, tab, orderDesc, actionValue]);
  const querySurvey = useMemo(
    () =>
      queriedSurvey?.pages
        .map((page) => page.edges.map((edge: object) => edge))
        .flat(),
    [queriedSurvey, search]
  );
...
...
const queryPlans = useMemo(
    () =>
      queriedPlans?.pages
        .map((page) => page.edges.map((edge: object) => edge))
        .flat(),
    [queriedPlans, actionSearch]
  );
  const onChange = (e: any) => {
    setActionValue(e);
  };
  console.log("isLoading", isLoading);
  if (isLoading) {
    return <Glimmer open={isLoading} />;
  }

  return (
....
....
```

when I console the "isLoading" at the initial call it is "true" otherwise it is "false" always.

Answer (score 2):

React-query has several flags in the object returned by the `useQuery` hook. Note that `isLoading` will only be true if there is no data and the query is currently fetching. Since you already have data and you invalidated it, the stale data will be present until the refetch is complete. Use the `isFetching` flag to determine if a fetching is in progress regardless of having stale data or not.